# retrieve data from cloud firestore with xamarin forms

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to retrieve data from firebase cloudstore from this path:

users> "user id" > posts >

a picture of the data i want to retrieve: [screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tioDH.png)

(im using plugin.CloudFirestore)

when i use this code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PostItem>> GetUserPostsList(string userId)
        {
            var group = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
                                     .Instance
                                     .GetCollectionGroup("Posts")
                                     .GetDocumentsAsync();

            var yourModels = group.ToObjects<PostItem>();

            return yourModels;
        }
```

i get the posts of all the users

i dont know how to set the path correctly

the function input "userId" is the Id key of the user i want the get the posts

when i try to use:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PostItem>> GetUserPostsList(string userId)
        {
            var group = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
                                     .Instance
                                     .GetCollectionGroup("Posts/" + userId +"/posts")
                                     .GetDocumentsAsync();

            var yourModels = group.ToObjects<PostItem>();

            return yourModels;
        }
```

i get this error: [screen shot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4pw8.png)

Comment: Have you tried [FieldPath](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore#fieldpath) which is listed in the document?

Comment: i got it working with: CrossCloudFirestore.Current.Instance.GetCollection("users/" + userId + "/Posts").GetDocumentsAsync();... thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, you can write this solution as an answer and mark it which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by this code:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<PostItem>> GetUserPostsList(string userId)
        {

            var group = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current.
                Instance.
                GetCollection("users/" + userId + "/Posts").
                GetDocumentsAsync();

            var yourModels = group.ToObjects<PostItem>();

            return yourModels;

        }
```